# Ouya not showing onscreen keyboard with LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, ouya

I have have serious problems getting the onscreen keyboard to show up on Ouya. Android works fine however. Ouya plays the sound for the keyboard opening, albeit kinda glitchy and what not, but doesn't show anything.

I'm using LibGDX. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still looking for an answer for this, below is a quick fix for Ouya textfields.

```
        final Input.TextInputListener nameListener = new Input.TextInputListener() {
            @Override
            public void input (String text) {
                textField.setText(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void canceled () {

            }
        };


        textField.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                Gdx.input.getTextInput(nameListener, "Please insert world name", "");
            }
        });
```